# how to limit time for input in python, windows?

Tags: python, input, time

I want to get string from user and limit the time for 5 sec, if he don't enter the string in this time print messege "no more time, bye!"
how to do it?
thanks you

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor the keyboard with something like [this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/134892) and include it in a timed loop.